# How to get Woocommerce Variation ID?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to create some additional functionality on my Woocommerce backend where I add a custom field to the variations section of backend of Woocommerce.  However I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the current variation id so I can get the post meta.

here is what I have been working with:

```
<?php

        // Get variations
        $args = array(
                     'post_type'     => 'product_variation',
                     'post_status'   => array( 'private', 'publish' ),
                     'numberposts'   => -1,
                     'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
                     'order'         => 'asc',
                     'post_parent'   => $post->ID
                 );
                 $variations = get_posts( $args ); 

        foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {

                     $variation_id           = absint( $variation->ID );$variable_id = $this['variation_id'];
                     $variation_post_status  = esc_attr( $variation->post_status );
                     $variation_data         = get_post_meta( $variation_id );
                     $variation_data['variation_post_id'] = $variation_id;
                    echo get_post_meta( $variation_data['variation_post_id'], '_my_custom_field', true) . ' - TEST';

                 }

     ?>
```

When I check the backend it looks like it is pulling all the post meta into each variation like this:

[image]

However if I use the actual variation id like the below then it works for that variation:

```
echo get_post_meta( 134, '_my_custom_field', true) . ' - Test Variation #134';
```

---

**UPDATE:**

---

Here is everything in its entirety in case this helps.

```
// Display Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'variable_fields' );
//JS to add fields for new variations
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes_js', 'variable_fields_js' );
// Save Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta_variable', 'variable_fields_process', 10, 1 );

function variable_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
?>  
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                    <label><?php _e( 'My Custom Field', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                    <input type="text" size="5" name="my_custom_field[<?php echo $loop; ?>]" value="<?php echo $variation_data['_my_custom_field'][0]; ?>"/>

      <?php
      if (isset( $_POST['variable_sku'] ) ) :
        $variable_sku = $_POST['variable_sku'];
        $variable_post_id = $_POST['variable_post_id'];
        $variable_custom_field = $_POST['my_custom_field'];
        for ( $i = 0; $i < sizeof( $variable_sku ); $i++ ) :
            $variation_id = (int) $variable_post_id[$i];
            if ( isset( $variable_custom_field[$i] ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_my_custom_field', stripslashes( $variable_custom_field[$i] ) );
            }
            echo get_post_meta( $variation_id, '_my_custom_field', true) . ' - Test';
        endfor;
    endif;

        //works echo get_post_meta( 134, '_my_custom_field', true) . ' - Test 134';



     ?>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}

function variable_fields_js() {
?>
<tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                    <label><?php _e( 'My Custom Field', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                    <input type="text" size="5" name="my_custom_field[' + loop + ']" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}

function variable_fields_process( $post_id ) {
    if (isset( $_POST['variable_sku'] ) ) :
        $variable_sku = $_POST['variable_sku'];
        $variable_post_id = $_POST['variable_post_id'];
        $variable_custom_field = $_POST['my_custom_field'];
        for ( $i = 0; $i < sizeof( $variable_sku ); $i++ ) :
            $variation_id = (int) $variable_post_id[$i];
            if ( isset( $variable_custom_field[$i] ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_my_custom_field', stripslashes( $variable_custom_field[$i] ) );
            }
        endfor;
    endif;
}
```

Comment: what is the context ? at which position you need to get the variation_id ? to add your field, are you using `woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes` hook, or what ?

Comment: Thanks @Shazzad, I updated the question to show my full code, yes I was using that hook.  Thanks for your help

Comment: The third argument `$variation` is a post object which has the id, ex `$variation->ID`. Other wise the $variation_data array also do have the id `$variation_data['variation_post_id']`. And for updating the values into meta, you can use `woocommerce_save_product_variation` hook, which comes with two argument `$$variation_id`, `$i` (index key/number)

Comment: When I try changing the get_post_meta to $variation->ID then I dont get anything to print on the admin product edit page.  Would you mind posting an example (im more of a visual learner) where I can see and test it?

Comment: Ok i will, however i am a little bit confused what you are trying to achieve ? can you please explain so that i can try to explain ?

Comment: All I need is a way to get the variation id when using the get_post_meta function.  As you see in the screenshot, I have a custom meta box at the bottom of each variation where someone will enter some info.  The data saves to the database no problem, but getting the variation id for get_post_meta seems to be my problem.  Currently if you type something in any of those boxes and hit "Update" then it does save but it does not show the data saved in the text box as seen in screenshot above.  For example I typed "opiolik" in the 1st variations meta box and used "qefqe" for the second meta box.

Comment: So my problem lies within the $variation_id not actually pulling the variation id in 'echo get_post_meta( $variation_id, '_my_custom_field', true) . ' - Test';'  But instead it is showing all variation meta data like in the screenshot for each.  If I use something like echo get_post_meta( 134, '_my_custom_field', true) . ' - Test';' then it works and shows _my_custom_meta data for variation #134..  I hope I havent confused you.  In short I just need a way to show the data that was entered once they hit update.  (It does save in the database just doesnt show when page refreshes)

Comment: Please try with that once - `<input type="text" size="5" name="my_custom_field[<?php echo $loop; ?>]" value="<?php echo get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_my_custom_field', true ); ?>"/>`

Comment: ehh, that didnt work either.. I put info into the text box and click save and it still does not show up?  Any other thoughts (PS Thank you so much for helping me with this)

Comment: Please avoid extended discussions in comments. If you need to clarify something, file an [edit] instead of a comment. @Shazzad If you think you got a solution, please post it as answer, not as comment. Thanks.